# Hiding whole DataTable and only show result rows from DataTables search

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTabel.
I am successfully linking custom input text with DataTables search function.
Are there a way to hide whole DataTable including footer and header and only show search result rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataTables [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option: `dom: 'ft'`

This causes only the `f` filter (search) box and the `t` table to be displayed.

You can hide the table's header and footer rows using CSS - for example, one way is to use:

```
<thead style="display: none;">
```

(It's better to place such styles in a CSS file, instead of embedding them inline in the HTML.)

The end result would be:

[image]

---

Live demo:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'ft'
  } );

} );
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Demo</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    </head>

    <body>

    <div style="margin: 20px;">

        <table id="example" class="display dataTable" style="width:100%">
            <thead style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office in Country</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office in Country</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```